# why my application doesnt show in android studio emulator

Tags: android, android-studio

i am able to run the emulator but does not show application in it, why? this is the code in activitymanifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.dell.phpmysql" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: what error you are getting when you run the app in studio. Post your logs in the Run console

Comment: C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\emulator.exe -avd Nexus_S_API_23 -netspeed full -netdelay none
emulator: device fd:696
HAXM is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
creating window 76 102 308 513
emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered

Comment: Hope your activity is in the package only com.example.dell.phpmysql? Can you please check this

Comment: what do you means? i dont get it. it inside got Application test, buildConfig, Main Activity, R and signupActivity

Comment: Here you launcher activity is MainActivity and It should in the package com.example.dell.phpmysql . The first line of your main Activity should have package com.example.dell.phpmysql; statement

Comment: what should i do now? can i have the codes. thank you

Comment: please post your full content of main activity

Answer (score 0):

**MainActivity**

```
package com.example.dell.phpmysql;

//import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private EditText etFullName, etUserName, etPassword, etPhone, etEmail;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        etFullName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etFullName);
        etUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUserName);
        etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
        etPhone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPhone);
        etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
    }

    public void signup(View v) {
        String fullName = etFullName.getText().toString();
        String userName = etUserName.getText().toString();
        String passWord = etPassword.getText().toString();
        String phoneNumber = etPhone.getText().toString();
        String emailAddress = etEmail.getText().toString();

        Toast.makeText(this, "Signing up...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        new SignupActivity(this).execute(fullName, userName, passWord, phoneNumber, emailAddress);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```